# Spring rest webservice with BasicAuth without xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I was wondering if it is possible to create Spring Webservice with BasicAuth without creating web.xml or any xml based configuration stuff.

I saw ton of tutorials to do it with xml, but I'd like to do this in class configuration way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm I'm sorry this may not be exact because I don't use this implementation anymore, I replaced with EE-based model BUT.... work with me here. :)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .withUser("fooserviceuser").password("$2a$10$9DvfxB.Sj2B/QznFRw85FenDvhUGglWWgOR7mmal/jNImhdHQRJgi").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
    .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
}
```

You also need an initializer to hook into the container like --

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

This uses bcrypt for password hashing. Sorry this isn't working code but I think there is enough here to put you on the right track! Google around for similar code snippets, they're there.